# Android 11 Beta Notification Bug

Tags: android, android-studio, push-notification, notifications, android-11

I was downloading files using google chrome and after some downloads, the download completed notification is not showing. At first it was showing with a tick icon on the notification shade. But now its not showing.

Same is with my other android app which I am building and testing with android 11 on Pixel 2. All notification permissions are allowed and I think its a bug. Apps that are not used frequently doesn't have this problem.

If anyone can help, please help.